# Blow up time depends continuously on initial data

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am given 
$$
u_t-\Delta u=u^3 \;\;(t,x)\in (0,T)\times \Omega,\;\;\;u(t)=0 \;\;in \; \partial \Omega, \;\;\;u(t=0)=\varphi \in \mathcal C_0(\Omega)
$$

It is also given that $\Omega$ is bounded and smooth domain. and $||\varphi||_{\infty}\leq K$

Blow up time of the equation $T(\varphi)$ is finite i.e. $T(\varphi)<\infty$.

And for $\delta $ small enough we have

$$
||u(t)||_{\infty}\leq C(K,\delta) \;\;\forall t\in [0,T(\phi)-\delta]
$$

see that $C(K,\delta)$ doesn't depend in initial data but only on $K$ and $\delta$.

I need to show that

$$
\varphi_n\rightarrow \varphi \;\;in\, C_0(\Omega)\implies T(\varphi_n)\rightarrow T(\varphi)
$$

It is already well known that $\varphi\rightarrow T(\varphi)$ is lower semicontinuous, we only need to show upper semicontinuity.

Please help.

Regards,
Harish